# Mysql contain string to get particular string in column

Tags: mysql

Please suggest how to get particular string from column without using like query.
example.

- Table name: notification
- Column 1: `notificationid`
- Column 2: `notification_to_id`

Sample data:

```
notificationid       notification_to_id
---------------------------------------
  1                        25,23   
  2                        15,16,25
```

How to get only 25 string alone from `notification_to_id` column?

Comment: multiple values in a single column...thats wrong normalization!!  each column should be normalized to contain only one value!!

Comment: @shalini,do you mean you want to get the max value?

Comment: no,not a max value i need to find the particular string @codelover

Comment: @codelover :  even `max` would fail here mate....note that `max` fetches max value for all column, but here, single column has multiple values from which u need to find a single value!!!

Comment: @NoobEditor,Ya you are right.Initially i did not follow what she wanted

Comment: @shalini : can explain the scenario in more elaborate way....why would u want to do this without normalizing the table properly!!???

Comment: Do you want the corresponding `notificationid` where the string exist??

Comment: @NoobEditor: Can you able to understand what i need exactly is,single column will have multiple values i need to get particular string which i am searching not a max value.Example if a column contain 12,14,13 i need to search whether that particular column having 12 string.I i used like query it showing every values as 12,13,14 i no need that i have to find only particular value 12 alone.Kindly do needful

Comment: @Gone: Not a corresponding notificationid. Need to search particular string 15 in column notification_to_id.

Comment: @shalini: Yeah i got that. If the string is found what should be the the result..That string itself??

Comment: @Gone:Ya correct i need that only

Answer (score 2):

try this one

```
SELECT notificationid,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(notification_to_id,','),',',value.v),',',-1) as to_id
FROM notification,(SELECT 1 as v UNION
                   SELECT 2 UNION
                   SELECT 3 UNION
                   SELECT 4 UNION
                   SELECT 5)value
HAVING to_id = '25'
```

[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/92b12/3)

So the query selects each element in the csv field by using `SUBSTRING_INDEX` with a `value.v` which will be anywhere from 1 to maximum 5 in this case ( *given by the `UNION` of `SELECT 1` ... `SELECT 5`* ). If it only has 3 elements in the csv field, when `value.v` is 4 or 5 it'll return empty string `''`.  And the `having` is to return rows that have 25 as element.

If `notification_to_id` contains more than 5 elements, just add more `UNION` like `SELECT 6` and so on up to the maximum number of elements in that column.

another method is to use the `REGEX` like below (but you have many occurences of 25 to replace

```
SELECT notificationid,
       '25' as value
FROM notification
WHERE notification_to_id REGEXP '(^25$)|(^25,)|(,25$)|(,25,)'
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fc0cd/4)

the above query will match if 25 is the only element (^25$) ^ marks start of string $ marks end of string. OR if 25  is the first item (^25,) OR if 25 is the last item (,25$) OR if 25 is somewhere in the middle (,25,)

Or if you want to use `LIKE` you use the below

```
SELECT notificationid,
       '25' as value
FROM notification
WHERE notification_to_id LIKE '25'
   OR notification_to_id LIKE '25,%'
   OR notification_to_id LIKE '%,25'
   OR notification_to_id LIKE '%,25,%'
```

[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fc0cd/5)

Comment: mmmmm....care explaining whats going on in this `sql`...looks rocket science to me!!!??? :)

Comment: yeah...i was right...it sure is rocket science!! :D

Comment: not it's not it's just the hack to get around the not-so normalized data